# How to access a List collection across winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list of this custom class.

```
public class Item
{
    public string @Url;
    public string Name;
    public double Price;

    public Item(string @url, string name, double price)
    {
        this.Url = url;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Price = price;
    }


    public void setPrice(Button button)
    {
        this.Price = Convert.ToDouble(button.Text);
    }
}
```

Now in my main winform this is declared

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
```

the fields are set through an add button as following they take information from 3 text boxes and store it in a new item.

```
Regex url = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|ca|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|CA|MIL|EDU)$");
Regex name = new Regex(@"^[0-9, a-z, A-Z, \-]+$");
Regex price = new Regex(@"^[0-9, \.]+$");

if (url.IsMatch(urlText.Text) && name.IsMatch(nameText.Text) && price.IsMatch(priceText.Text))
{
     itemListBox.Items.Add(nameText.Text);
     double item_Price = Convert.ToDouble(priceText.Text);
     items.Add(new Item(@itemURL.Text, itemName.Text, item_Price));
     nameText.Clear();
     priceText.Clear();
     urlText.Clear();
}
else
{
     match(url, urlText, urlLabel);
     match(price, priceText, priceLabel);
     match(name, nameText, nameLabel);
}
```

As you can see in the above code it also adds the name of the item to an item list box. Now I have another windows form that pop's up when the edit button is clicked. How can i make the item list box in the edit form show exactly like the item list box from the main windows form?

In a basic question how can i transfer the list of items to the edit form. I've tried passing it through a constructor because I want the edited information to remain constant no matter what winform. the constructor was declared in the Edit Form:

```
public Edit(List<Item> i)
{
    itemList = i;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

When i loaded up the list box

```
foreach (Item i in itemList)
{
   itemListBox.Items.Add(i.Name);
}
```

the list box shows Name instead of the actual value of name

UPDATE 1: [image: No work]

UPDATE 2:

My main winform code http://pastebin.com/mENGKdnJ

The edit winform code http://pastebin.com/tvp95jQW

don't pay attention to the open file dialog I don't know how to code it yet so far coding this program has taught me a lot because i learn as i go.

Comment: OK, so you tried something (`ref` is not needed at all by the way). What happened?

Comment: put a breakpoint on _itemListBox.Items.Add(i.Name);_ to confirm the .Name contains "Name".

Comment: Tip: If you want to be the editform to be blocking the mainform until it's close, use ShowDialog() instead of Show()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to send a list as ref, the ref is only needed when changing the (pointer)instance itself. Adding/removing items doesn't affect the lists instance.

Updated:

The listbox uses the ToString() to present some description for the item.

```
public class Item
{
    public string @Url;
    public string Name;
    public double Price;

    public Item(string @url, string name, double price)
    {
        this.Url = url;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Price = price;
    }


    public void setPrice(Button button)
    {
        this.Price = Convert.ToDouble(button.Text);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // example: return string.Format("{0} -> {1}", this.Name, this.Price);
        return this.Price;
    }
```

}

So you should not add the name, but the object

```
foreach (Item i in itemList)
{
   itemListBox.Items.Add(i);
}
```

---

in addiction (minor tip)

```
public class Item
{
    public string @Url {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public double Price {get; set;}

    public Item(string @url, string name, double price)
    {
        this.Url = url;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Price = price;
    }
}
```

The SetPrice  (conversion to double should not be placed here)

update ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

I think i see it:

```
if (url.IsMatch(urlText.Text) && name.IsMatch(nameText.Text) && price.IsMatch(priceText.Text))
{
     itemListBox.Items.Add(nameText.Text);
     double item_Price = Convert.ToDouble(priceText.Text);
     items.Add(new Item(@itemURL.Text, itemName.Text, item_Price));
     nameText.Clear();
     priceText.Clear();
     urlText.Clear();
}
```

You add **nameText**.Text to the listbox, but you pass **itemName**.Text to the item constructor.

Same with **urlText**.Text in the regex matcher, but **itemURL**.Text is passed to the constructor.

Comment: Made all the changes suggested but unfortunatly Im still stuck with the same problem check main post for picture of what shows up.

Comment: Did you check the contents on the list? put a breakpoint on itemListBox.Items.Add(i.Name); to confirm the i.Name contains "Name", I think a empty list is passed to you edit form. And Name is default contents of the listbox

Comment: I put a breakpoint the following values are there

Name = "Name"
Price is the right value 
URL = "URL"

Comment: sorry for the unclear part i.Name = "Name" yes that is wrong which is why i dont understand only the price got transfered everything else is not correct

Comment: Updated with pastebin links in main post

Comment: Wow how did I miss that thank you!! I was adding the text of the Labels no wonder! Thanks for the great spot!